# Open email from my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a game with Cocos and Sprite Builder in Objective-C, and I'm finishing the support scene but I have a problem. I want to add a button that when clicked, it opens directly the email with my address so that the users can contact me if there is some problems.

What code do I need to write to accomplish this?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: There are many sample codes to accomplish this. Please search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the MessageUI framework and then :

```
- (void)showMailSender
{
    if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        NSLog(@"MFMailComposeViewController can't send emails.");
        return;
    } else {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailComposeViewController setSubject:@"Subject"];
        [mailComposeViewController setToRecipients:@[@"example@domain.com"]];
        [self presentViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [controller.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: sorry i tried now, nut it say to me that presentViewController and dismissViewControllerAnimated is not declered in the @interface

Comment: This code needs to be added to a view controller subclass. Where did you add it ?

Comment: mm because i created my app with sprite builder